# How to create a bottom toolbar for Android using Xamarin forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I've been working on two Xamarin forms projects and both require a bottom toolbar across iOS and Android.  I've been struggling to put together the bottom toolbar for Android using Xamarin forms.  I tried to write a custom TabbedRenderer for Android but can't seem to find the right method to override to push the tabs to the bottom.  I also tried to use a StackLayout at the bottom of every page for the tabs but the result doesn't look very good - when switching tab, the tabs flash as they are loaded as part of the page.

Is there any better solution for writing a bottom toolbar with Xamarin forms or is there a "native" bottom toolbar coming with Xamarin forms in the near future as Google is now officially embracing bottom navigation with an update to the Material Design spec.?

Thanks!

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.App;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(ylbCross.Droid.CustomTabRenderer))]

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class CustomTabRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        private Activity _activity;

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {

            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            _activity = this.Context as Activity;


        }

        public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasWindowFocus)
        {   
            ActionBar actionBar = _activity.ActionBar;

            if (actionBar.TabCount > 0)
            {
                ActionBar.Tab tabOne = actionBar.GetTabAt(0);
                tabOne.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.home_Blue48);

                tabOne.TabSelected += (sender, e) => {
                    tabOne.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.home_Blue);
                };
                tabOne.TabUnselected += (sender, e) => {
                    tabOne.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.home_Grey);
                };

                ActionBar.Tab tabTwo = actionBar.GetTabAt(1);
                tabTwo.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.QA_Grey);
                tabTwo.TabSelected += (sender, e) => {
                    tabTwo.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.QA_Blue);
                };
                tabTwo.TabUnselected += (sender, e) => {
                    tabTwo.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.QA_Grey);
                };

                ActionBar.Tab tabThree = actionBar.GetTabAt(2);
                tabThree.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.consulting_Grey);
                tabThree.TabSelected += (sender, e) => {
                    tabThree.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.consulting_Blue);
                };
                tabThree.TabUnselected +=   (sender, e) => {
                    tabThree.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.consulting_Grey);
                }

                ActionBar.Tab tabFour = actionBar.GetTabAt(3);
                tabFour.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.aboutMe_Grey);
                tabFour.TabSelected += (sender, e) => {
                    tabFour.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.aboutMe_Blue);
                };
                tabFour.TabUnselected +=    (sender, e) => {
                    tabFour.SetIcon (Resource.Drawable.aboutMe_Grey);
                }

            }

            base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is duplicated.
You can find the solution here:

[Duplicated question answer (XF Bottom navigation bar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746102/xamarinforms-pagetypes/44748020#44748020)

In summary, you should use **a third party control** or if you are a good designer, you can easily create your own bottom bar.

The proposed component in this answer, **use Material Design** for Android platform.
Don't forget to mark as answered if this answer is correct for you.